# iBatis/MyBatis Entity Maps to DDL Reverse generation

Tags: reverse-engineering, mybatis, ddl

I am looking for a way to generate DDL out of existing iBatis sql entity mappings ? Is there any i could not find on the net.

Comment: this isn't really the intent of Mybatis.  I'd start by checking for tools around the DB you're using.  For example Oracle might do something like this http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1464804639878